# Retrieve all past revisions for a given key

Tags: key-value, etcd, revision-history

I am trying to get the past 3 revisions for the key "Chops"
`/opt/etcd/etcdctl get "Chops" --order=DESCEND --sort-by=MODIFY --limit=3`

However, I am just getting a single KV back.
That would be preferred if there's a way to do this in the Go library. But for now, I am trying to understand how to do this. It doesn't look like it's a current feature and there's not much on the web around this topic. If anyone has figured this out, I'd be grateful!

Comment: Looks like you need `--rev`, and multiple calls. See [this](https://etcd.io/docs/v3.3/dev-guide/interacting_v3/#read-past-version-of-keys).

Comment: The question looks the same as [that one](https://stackoverflow.com/q/72564508/720999).

Comment: The same question [in the `etcd` issue tracker](https://github.com/etcd-io/etcd/issues/11027).

Comment: @kostix - https://etcd.io/docs/v3.3/dev-guide/interacting_v3/#read-past-version-of-keys
This would work if you knew the keys revisions upfront... However as the title suggests we don't have these, so your answer is pointless.
I need a way of finding all the revisions for a given key

Answer (score 0):

I managed to solve this issue by creating a loop and iterating between the CreateRevision and ModRevision. Doing a get request for each iteration and appending them all to a list within the loop. Not pretty but works very well.